# Why are the hyperlinks in my buttons not working on the second line?

Tags: html, css

Why aren't my hyperlinks clickable (working) in my buttons on the second line of text?

[image: image1]

here is the working [Link](https://heathology.github.io/)

I am including my html code and my css code below. I thought that the CSS for the button or button container or button fill might be cutting of the link, but I am not figuring it out. The solution is evading me. Does anyone else have any thoughts after reviewing the code below?

```css
/* CSS file, created by heathology, https://heathology.github.io/, on 7.17.2002. 
Gradient buttons adapted from Zach Cole (https://codepen.io/zachacole/pen/KdGzgb).*/

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* logo */
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 336px;
}

h1, p {
    text-align: center; 
}

/* Main Content Container */
.content {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 520px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .content {
        width: 50%;
      }
     
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .content {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
}
/* 2778x1284 pixels at 458ppi */
@media only screen 
    and (device-width: 428px) 
    and (device-height: 926px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
    
    }

/* Project Navigation Links */
.nav {
    text-align: center;
}

/* infite gradient shift on hover buttons */

#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.button-container {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0 0 15px auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 12px 0 rgba(152, 160, 180, 10);
    z-index: -2;
    display: inline-block;
    color:aliceblue;
}


.fill-one {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4);
    background-size: 150% 150%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.button-container-one:hover .fill-one {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
}

.fill-two {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4);
    background-size: 150% 150%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.button-container-two:hover .fill-two {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
}

.fill-three {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E040FB, #00BCD4);
    background-size: 150% 150%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -140px;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.button-container-three:hover .fill-three {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
@-webkit-keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <title>heathology's Github Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="content">
        <header><h1>Hello World!</h1></header>
        <div><img class="logo" src="img/Heath-Media-Designs-Logo-2022.png" width="500" height="560"></div>
        <p>My name is Jesse Heath, aka heathology. <br>I am a self taught web developer and graphic designer. <br>HTML and WordPress are my forte.</p>
        <h1>My Projects</h1>
        <div id="outer">
            <div class="button-container button-container-one inner">
                <a href="cafe-menu/index.html"><button>
                Cafe Menu
                <div class="fill-one"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container button-container-two inner">
                <a href="registration-form/index.html"><button>
                Registration Form
                <div class="fill-two"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <a href="survey-form/index.html"><button>
                Survey Form
                <div class="fill-three"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <a href="rothko-painting/index.html"><button>
                Rothko Painting
                <div class="fill-three"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <a href="css-flexbox-photo-gallery/index.html"><button>
                CSS Flexbox Photo Gallery
                <div class="fill-three"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <a href="css-nutrition-label/index.html"><button>
                CSS Typography Nutrition Label
                <div class="fill-three"></div>
            </button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Provide `<a>` design of the button instead of using both. Remove the button tag inside a tag.

Comment: The hyperlinks in the above mentioned website are working fine. Are you facing issues replicating it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links themselves are working, but they don't take up the full space of their container. So, some parts of the button don't result in a redirect.

To fix this, all you have to do is set the [display to block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Links `<a>` are automatically set to `display: inline` in css, which causes them not to fill their container. This selector will make all the links, which are direct children of your buttons, fit the container.

```css
.button-container > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Quincy. This worked (but I just removed the ">" which I assumed was a typo).

Comment: @heathology The ">" is actually not a typo. This is the [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) in css, which will select only direct children of an element (not recursive). This ensures that if nested links are added later, they would not be affected. In your situation, it makes no difference, but it is generally a good practice to use this selector because recursively selecting children can lead to unexpected problems later.

Comment: I feel dumb now. Oh well, I'm still learning CSS. :) Thanks for the clarification and advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content">
    <header>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </header>
    <div><img class="logo" src="img/Heath-Media-Designs-Logo-2022.png" width="500" height="560"></div>
    <p>My name is Jesse Heath, aka heathology. <br>I am a self taught web developer and graphic designer.
        <br>HTML and WordPress are my forte.</p>
    <h1>My Projects</h1>
    <div id="outer">
        <a href="cafe-menu/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-one inner">
                <button>
                    Cafe Menu
                    <div class="fill-one"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="registration-form/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-two inner">
                <button>
                    Registration Form
                    <div class="fill-two"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="survey-form/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <button>
                    Survey Form
                    <div class="fill-three"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="rothko-painting/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <button>
                    Rothko Painting
                    <div class="fill-three"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="css-flexbox-photo-gallery/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <button>
                    CSS Flexbox Photo Gallery
                    <div class="fill-three"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="css-nutrition-label/index.html">
            <div class="button-container button-container-three inner">
                <button>
                    CSS Typography Nutrition Label
                    <div class="fill-three"></div>
                </button>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please replace this html code. You have to link whole div.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add css:

```
.button-container a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add Important Property.

```
.button-container { !important;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
width: 220px;
margin: 0 0 15px auto;
cursor: pointer;
```

}